# Networkx giving strongly connected check not defined

Tags: python, networkx, strongly-connected-graph

I'm using networkx(first time) to check the graph is strongly connected or nt but i'm getting that its not defined. As document stated it should work.??

My run :

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
w = [(0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2,4), (3,1) , (1,3)]
G.add_edges_from(w)

#Check if strongly connected
is_strongly_connected(G)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in
>
> NameError: name 'is_strongly_connected' is not defined

Thanks

Comment: Searched through the whole code its not there ?? How should i get it as an interface ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `nx.is_strongly_connected(G)`?

Comment: Thank ya. very much ..